# How do I get rc.local to run at startup?

Tags: startup

I've looked at various methods, and none have worked for me.  I'm trying to run

```
sudo xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'
```

on startup, to get the keyboard light to be bound to scroll lock.  I can use that command from a terminal and it works fine, and I've added it to rc.local, and going in the terminal and saying

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rc.local start
```

works fine.  But when I restart the computer again, apparently rc.local doesn't execute.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: The commands in `/etc/rc.local` run as `root`..remove `sudo` :  put `xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'` in `/etc/rc.local` (before `exit 0`) and then check..

Comment: The `man` page for `xmodmap` says `utility for modifying keymaps and pointer button mappings in X`. At boot time, when `/etc/rc.local` runs, the X window system has not yet started. How can this possibly work?